# When is Pinsker’s inequality tight?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ be two distributions of $\mathbf{x}$. Pinsker’s inequality says

$$D(P(x)\|Q(x)) \geq \frac{1}{2 \ln 2} \|P(x) - Q(x)\|_1^2,$$

where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the $\mathcal{L}^1$ norm, and $D(P(x)\|Q(x))$ is the KL-divergence

$$D(P(x)\|Q(x)) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} P(x)\log_2 \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} dx.$$

Given that $\int x^2 P(x) dx \neq \int x^2 Q(x) dx$ (Second moment constraint).

My question is when Pinsker’s inequality is tight. Thanks!

PS: My previous question is without the second moment contraint. In that case, $P = Q$ (a.e.) can make Pinsker's inequality tight.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.07118.pdf This might help. Better constants compared to $1/(2\ln 2)$ are found and tightness of them is studied extensively in this paper.

Comment: @stud_iisc Thanks very much for your comments. Could you provide me an easy example please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps it'd be more simple to look for easy examples (better bounds compared to Pinsker's) in this paper : http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~williams/papers/P180.pdf

Comment: @stud_iisc Thanks so much for your help :-)